# "Observed node inconsistent " when binomial success rate exactly one

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, jags

I observed some curious behavior in JAGS (rjags). There probably is a good reason for it, but I can't figure it out:

As part of a more complex model I have these statements:

```
p[n] <- min(sum(c[,n]) / reps[n],0.99999999999999) 
y[n] ~ dbin(p[n],reps[n])
```

Like this, the overall model works (returning expected parameters for constructed data).

The min(...,0.99999999999999) part, however, is a workaround that was required to make it run. Apparently, when a p[n] becomes exactly 1 (which can happen based on the sum), I get: "Observed node inconsistent with unobserved parents at initialization.".

I wonder whether there is fundamental reason (likelihood undefined?), a technical, or whether it maybe is a bug.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

P.S.: I'm also interested whether this is a common way to limit a quantity in the model or if I should/can do it somehow else.

Comment: Just a question: when `p[n]` is = 1.0 , what is `y[n]`? I was thinking that maybe you only get the error when `p[n] == 1` and `y[n] < reps[n]`. Then the error message make sense as the observed node (`y[n]`) sort of is inconsistent with it's parent (`p[n]`). That is when `p[n] == 1` then `y[n] < reps[n]` is logically impossible.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure whether I understand it. But maybe this clarifies: y[n] is the observed data. It's always an integer. For p[n] == 1, y[n] should be the maximum possible value (reps[n]). 

Can the division be a problem? Does JAGS produce a float when I divide two integers (the sum is always an int, so is the value from reps[n]; y[n] is int, too). Is there a way to explicitly cast types (or implicitly some by some operation)?

Comment: `library(rjags);`

`ms <- "model{ y ~ dbin(1, 5) }";`

`m <- jags.model(textConnection(ms), list(y=5));`

When compiling the following model you get your error when y is less than 5. Your problem (I think) is that for some `p[n] == 1` `y[n]` is less than `reps[n]`. If you can figure out why that is the case (and if it really should be the case) you are on your way solve it, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for testing. Hmm, this somehow reminds me of problems with chi-square goodness-of-fit less for cells with 5 or less observations. I don't remember the details. Also I don't know whether the Gibbs sampler uses something that could have the same problems to evaluate the goodness of a sample. I will investigate. A lot of stuff comes up on Google for ' binomial  "less than five observations" '.

Comment: Oh and one addition: I also produced the same behavior in a similar model with p[n] == 0 where I had to use max(..., 0.000000001) as a workaround.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with 5. The problem is that `dbin(1.0, n)` can't logically support any other outcome than `n`, as you have 100% success for each of the `n` trials. Writing `1 ~ dbin(1.0, 2)` is like writing -1 ~ Poisson(0.4), as the outcome of a Poisson distribution can't be negative.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. So it is just a consequence of the discreteness introduced by the sum. So do you think the workaround is appropriate? Many thanks!

Comment: Perhaps, but I can't really tell without the context. However, something is a bit strange when `sum(c[,n]) / reps[n]` can become 1 when y[n] is clearly contradicting this.

Comment: I think that can be the case because the processes that generate the c[,n] may produce c[,n] that fit well at certain levels n but not at the one where sum(c[,n]) / reps[n].